# Get rows from the beginning of the current hour

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have data stored in a mySQL database and I want to retrieve the rows that have been inserted between now and the beginning of the current hour: not in the last hour, since the start of the hour. For example, at 9:16 I want the rows from 9:00 until now. My time is stored in datatime format. How can I do this?

Comment: From a specific table or from the database as a whole?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is:

```
select *
from t
where date(now() ) = date(t.timeval) and
      hour(now() ) = hour(t.timeval)
```

I made the assumption that you don't have future records in the data.  If so, then this comes to mind:

```
select *
from t
where date(now() ) = date(t.timeval) and
      hour(now() ) = hour(t.timeval) and
      timeval < now()
```

Comment: so you're worrying about rows that have been entered in the future!?!?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . The question doesn't specify what the data is.  They could be expected times of cmopletions, for instance, rather than transaction times.  My real concern is I always forget in MySQL the timestamp types and when they work with datetimes.  Too complicated.

Comment: This query applies functions to both sides of the argument. This slows things down and should always be avoided if possible. But hey, it's your dime.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . It is not that the query applies functions to both sides.  It is that the function is applied to `timeval`, which would generally preclude the use of an index.  The use of a function on a constant such as `now()` should not affect optimization.

Answer (score 12):

The query below selects all rows that are between the current hour and current time. So if current time is **10:11** it will select all rows between **10:00** and **10:11** within current date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test
WHERE mytime BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') 
             AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

I Tested it and worked.

Comment: . . Nor why I was downvoted.  Someone seems to have just gone through and downvoted everyone.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM times WHERE t >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00');
```

Comment: I do not understand your query. Your are querying the database for future times. The result will be empty. Time greater than now is you query in words.

Comment: @Mr.Radical No it isn't. He is truncating the minutes and seconds.

Comment: Except as originally presented it won't find the entries that are exactly on the hour, hence the edit.

Comment: Can I have my demerit back then? ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry from me? I didn't take it.